# Image display with details in textbox on another form

Tags: vb.net

Why my code doesn't work, In form4 you can upload a pic then there's a textbox there where you can type the details of the pic then if you click submit button, Form5 will show and the picture that you upload in form4 will show in form5 picturebox and the typed details in textbox in form4 will also appear in form5 label1. Can you correct my code (I'm not using database)
When I already upload the pic, typed the details and click submit button it doesn't show on form5

```
Public Class Form4

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim file As New OpenFileDialog

    file.Filter = "Image files | *.png; *.jpg; *.gif |" & _
                    "All files (*.*) | *.*"
    file.FilterIndex = 1

    If file.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        PictureBox1.ImageLocation = file.FileName
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Me.Hide()
    Form3.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Me.PictureBox1.Image = Form5.PictureBox1.Image
    Me.TextBox1.Text = Form5.Label1.Text

    MsgBox("Ad Posted!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    Me.Hide()
    Form5.Show()
    TextBox1.Clear()

End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim lbutton As DialogResult
    lbutton = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to logout now?", "Logging out", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
    If lbutton = DialogResult.Yes Then
        Form1.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form4_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles     MyBase.Load
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, True)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: what is it exactly that "doesn't work"?

Comment: When I already upload the pic, typed the details and click submit button it doesn't show on form5, the submit button is button2

Comment: By your explanation, your code is backwards. Don't you want to assign `Form5.PictureBox1.Image = Me.PictureBox1.Image` ?